# Getting the Maximum Average price based on Product Name

Tags: mysql

I have a Products table with three headers namely ProductID, ProductName and Price.I need to find the name of the product which is having maximum average price. There are multiple products and they are duplicate as well for different product ID and i need their average price.
Sample Data looks like below :

```
ProductID   ProductName Price
1   A   18
2   A   19
3   B   10
4   C   22
5   D   21.35
6   C   25
7   A   30
8   B   40
9   E   97
10  A   31
```

Query that i have written is as below:

```
SELECT ProductName
FROM Products
group by ProductName
order by avg(Price) desc
limit 1;
```

But i was informed that it is not a generic solution. Can anyone please inform, what is wrong in this query.

Comment: When i see brackets i see a SQL Server valid query not a MySQL valid query

Comment: What is desired result ?

Comment: Also LIMIT is only a MySQL, MariaDB, PostgreSQL and i believe SQLite also has LIMIT ...for limiting you should be looking into SQL standards FETCH FIRST n ROWS but only problem not all databases support it.. i very much doubt you can rewrite this query into a 100% pure generic solution which works in all database systems

Comment: Hi Raymond, thanks for the quick response. Sorry for the confusion forgot to remove brackets. Its related to MySQL query.

Comment: You have a group by clause without any aggregate function in the select list.

Comment: So what's the purpose of `GROUP BY` without aggregation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem with your query is the case where there are more than 1 products with average price equal to the maximum average price, because it returns only 1 row.
To cover this case you need to group again and use your query in the HAVING clause :

```
select productname
from products
group by productname
having avg(price) = ( 
  select avg(price) 
  from products
  group by productname
  order by avg(price) desc 
  limit 1
);
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uXmdXdRAA2UGxML4VCdori/1).

Comment: Why not drop the **group by** clause and replace **having** with **where**?

Comment: Because the OP wants the max average price of the products and not the average price of all the rows of the table.